# Grant permissions between AWS resources with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I would like to have a CloudFormation template create an EC2 instance and give that instance access to a S3 bucket.

One way is to have the template create an IAM user with proper permissions and use its access key to grant access.

But what if I don't want to give that user access to the IAM service?
Is there a way to have that user deploy this template without IAM?

UPDATE:

I want to be able to just share that template, so I am wondering if it is possible to not have a dependency on pre-existing IAM resources (roles, policies, etc)

Comment: Are you concerned with the instance having proper permissions to access the bucket? or with the user permissions required to run the template?

Comment: with the user permissions required to run the template because the template creates IAM resources.

Comment: I think you want a Cloudformation Service Role http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html

Answer (score 0):

The common method to grant permissions for an instance is [Instance Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html). You create a role with all the required permissions, assign that role to an instance profile and then assign the profile to any instance you need.

You can [do this with CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenarios-iamroles):

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
   "Resources": {
      "myEC2Instance": {
         "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "Version": "2009-05-15",
         "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-205fba49",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
               "Ref": "RootInstanceProfile"
            }
         }
      },
      "MyRole": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [ {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Principal": {
                     "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ]
                  },
                  "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
               } ]
            },
            "Path": "/"
         }
      },
      "RolePolicies": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
         "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "s3",
            "PolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [ {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action":["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl"],
                  "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
               } ]
            },
            "Roles": [ { "Ref": "MyRole" } ]
         }
      },
      "RootInstanceProfile": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
         "Properties": {
            "Path": "/",
            "Roles": [ { "Ref": "MyRole" } ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to avoid giving the user deploying this template IAM access, you can create the instance profile before deploying the template and specify the already existing instance profile in the template. I haven't tried that yet, but it seems that should only require [`ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AssociateIamInstanceProfile.html) and you should be able to constrain that just to that one specific profile.

Comment: The downside is that the template needs prerequisites to work. Thanks for the feedback though, there may not be any way around it.

Comment: Either way you have prerequisites. It can be access key, instance profile, or a bucket that's open to everybody in your account. But the bucket itself is also a prerequisite, so I'd consider this an extension of the bucket configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by IAM service.

You can create IAM User Access Keys that give permissions to specific AWS services and no others. Access Keys do not allow IAM Console Access (this requires login credentials or federation).

For your use case your user will need at a minimum:

- Permission to use CloudFormation to execute your template.
- Permission to create the EC2 instance.

These permissions are defined in a policy that you add to the IAM user in the AWS Management Console. You can create users that cannot log into the console. Then you generate the Access Keys that the user will use in their application, AWS CLI, etc.

[Overview of IAM Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html?shortFooter=true)

Comment: This doesn't answer how to configure the permissions of the ec2 instance itself to s3.

Comment: I did not see that request in your question. Just the part about deploying the template. I will update my answer. Please edit your question with the permissions required for S3 for your EC2 role.